# Are ghost touch weapons the only way to bypass the 50% chance to ignore damage against or by incorporeal creatures?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons, damage, incorporeal

When others attack (with spells and magic weapons or such abilities) you while you are incorporeal, you have a 50% chance to ignore the damage. When you attack while incorporeal, you also have a 50% chance of not harming your opponent (while attacking with a spell or magic weapon).

Are ghost touch weapons the only way to bypass that drawback?

Answer (score 10):

The d20srd.org entry on [Incorporeal Creatures](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype) has the answers you seek:

There is no 50% miss chance for Incorporeal creatures hitting other creatures unless the incorporeal creature is within a solid body (and thus can't see its target, granting it total concealment.  An incorporeal creature's attacks ignore armor, natural armor and shield bonuses so they can be quite accurate against many foes!

The following ways can damage an incorporeal creature without having to worry about the 50% miss chance:

- positive energy
- negative energy
- force effects such as magic missile
- attacks made with ghost touch weapons

Comment: The incorporeal subtype in Monster Manual 3 and Tome of battle state that an incorporeal creature's attacks with melee wepons that are not magical have no effect, and that with magical weapons the creature suffers a 50% miss chance. Your link states otherwise. What is oficial from these two?

Comment: @Khaal - interesting, I don't know

Comment: MM3 page 214 under the Incorporeal Subtype and ToB page 79 can be found this: Nonmagical attacks made by an incorporeal creature with 
a melee weapon have no effect on corporeal targets, and any 
melee attack an incorporeal creature makes with a magic 
weapon against a corporeal target has a 50% miss chance, 
except for attacks it makes with a ghost touch weapon, while 
are made normally (no miss chance).

Comment: To be really clear, it states that this is an *update* to the rules.  (Why they never printed it as errata I don't know.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, MM1 is the primary source for its contents; neither ToB nor MM3 have the authority to modify the Incorporeal subtype globally (though they may do so for their own creatures). To globally modify the Incorporeal subtype would require MM1 errata, which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Derp, forgot to add the link: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56771/where-are-the-rules-about-what-sources-are-primary

Comment: Minnmass have a look at the "rule compendium" . In the first line in the introduction it is stated as follows: "The book you hold in your hands is the definitive guide for how to play the 3.5 revision of the Dungeon and Dragons role-play gaming". Then have a look at page 64 (incorporeal subtype)

Comment: @Digius: is there an errata to MM1 or PhB (which talks about primary sources) that allows the rules compendium to supersede it? Barring such an errata, the rules compendium doesn't have the authority to claim that it's definitive. While its change to the incorporeal subtype may be good (I haven't used it yet), it cannot override the MM1 entry.

Comment: I believe that just reading the introduction of the rule compendium it comes out cristal clear.  If we question this the next question for you is how would you manage 2 different rules for the same subtype of creature (incorporeal)? And when it comes to a character becoming incorporeal, do you follow MM1 or MM3? Last thing to add is that rules for incorporeals in the rule compendium are the same as for the incorporeal rules in MM 3 an the spell ghostform in the spell compendium) and they al differ from the MM1 (which was printed before the other books mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

Transdimensional Spell is a feat that was originally in [*Unapproachable East*](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/28722/Unapproachable-East-35) (p. 45) and now is in [*Complete Arcane*](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/3733/Complete-Arcane-35) (p. 84) and [*Complete Divine*](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/28308/Complete-Divine-35) (p. 85). It allows one to cast spells that affect incorporeal creatures as though they were corporeal.

There are also spells and effects from [*Ghostwalk*](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/169140/Ghostwalk-3e) that can drag incorporeal creatures into manifested corporeal bodies.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is divided in 2 parts

1. when a corporeal creature wants to attack an incorporeal and ignore the 50% miss chance
2. when a incorporeal creature wants to attack a corporeal and ignore the 50% miss chance

**1 PART) When a corporeal creature wants to attack an incorporeal**

The incorporeal subtipe from "Rule compendium" 64 states the following:

> An incorporeal creature can be harmed only by **other incorporeal**
> creatures, magic weapons or creatures that strike as magic weapons,
> and spells, spell-like abilities, or supernatural abilities.
> Even when hit by spells (including touch spells) or magic weapons, an
> incorporeal creature has a 50% chance to ignore any damage from a
> corporeal source

continues

> **except** for positive energy, negative energy, force
> effects such as magic missile, or attacks made with ghost touch
> weapons.

So by description of incorporeal subtype the following are ways to ignore the 50% miss chance:

**By Type of Spells:**
Incorporeals are affected without miss chance by enchants:

- positive energy
- negative energy
- force effects (such as magic missile)

**By Weapons**

- attacks made with [ghost touch weapons](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Ghost_Touch_(Weapon_Enhancement))

**By Feat**

- Transdimensional spell  - *Complete Divine* page 85

> A transdimensional spell has full, normal effect upon incorporeal
> creatures, creatures on the Ethereal Plane or Plane of Shadow, and
> creatures within an extradimensional space in the spell’s area

- Incorporeal Target fighting - *Ghostwalk*, page 36

> in meelee, everytime you miss because of a creatures incrporeal's
> miss chance, you can reroll your miss chance percentile roll one time
> to see if you actually hit

- pierce magical concealment - *complete arcane* page 81

This is applied if you are attacking an enemy that became incorporeal through a spell.

> Your fierce contempt for magic allows you to disregard the miss chance
> granted by spells or spell-like abilities such as darkness, blur,
> invisibility, obscuring mist, ghostform (see page 109), and spells
> when used to create concealment effects (such as a wizard using
> permanent image to fill a corridor with illusory fire and smoke). In
> addition, when facing a creature protected by mirror image, you can
> immediately pick out the real creature from its figments. Your ability
> to ignore the miss chance granted by magical concealment doesn't grant
> you any ability to ignore nonmagical concealment (so you would still
> have a 20% miss chance against an invisible creature hiding in fog,
> for example).

**By the strategy of becoming yourself incorporeal**
why? - in the "rule compendium" (64) it is not mentioned that incorporeals have any miss chance of attacking other incorporeals.

Becoming incorporeal by a *spell* some examples are as follows:

- *one with shadow* - level 8 -*Tome of Battle* page 78
- *ghost form* - level 8 - *Spell Compendium* page 103
- THIS DOES NOT WORK (thanks for the note -Hey I Can Chan-) *Polymorph any object* - level 8 - *Player's handbook* page 263
- *greater wish* - level 9 - Player's handbook
- *umbral body* - level 8 - *Tome of Magic* page 152

By *class feature*:

- Shadow form - at level 3 of the Perfect Wight - *Epic Level handbook*
  pag. 34
- ghost strike - at level 8 of the Ninja  - *Complete Adventurer* page 8
- spirit form - level 9 of the Spirit Shaman's - *Complete Divine* page 15

**Becoming a ghost**
Becoming Ethereal (*Rule Compendium* page 41) does not mean becoming incorporeal as only ghosts have the power to *manifest* (while being in the etheral plane they manifest as incorporeals in the material plane). This is also discussed [in a previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122442/etherealness-and-the-incorporeal-subtype-while-blinking#:%7E:text=So%20yes%2C%20the%20blink%20description,that%20ethereal%20creatures%20are%20incorporeal.).

So if you make yourself becoming a ghost you could use the same strategy.

- ghostform spell from *Spell Compendium* (108) mentioned above

**By the strategy of making the incorporeal corporeal with a spell**

- ghost trap - level 5 spell - *Spell Compendium* 103
- forced manifestation - *ghostwalk* page 52

---

**2 PART) When an incorporeal creature wants to attack an corporeal**

By description of incorporeal subtype above (*Rules compendium* page 64) the following are ways to ignore the 50% miss chance:

**Use a spell**
WHY? - Because spells have ha 50% miss chance if casted by a corporeal to attack an incorporeal, but incorporeal creatures casting a spell on corporeals have no miss chance. (not symmetric rule)

** By Feat**

- pierce magical concealment *complete arcane* 81
  This is applied if you made yourself incorporeal through a class feature that is either (mag) or (SOP) and you attack attack someone that is corporeal

**By Weapons**

- attacks made with [ghost touch weapons](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Ghost_Touch_(Weapon_Enhancement))
- attack with a ranged weapon, they will become corporeal as soon as you stop touching them (buy you will be able to touch them again unless you turn corporeal)

**Becoming corporeal by a casting a *spell* on yourself some examples are as follows:**

- ghost trap - level 5 spell - spell compendium 103

**By Feat**
Ghostly [grasp](https://realmshelps.net/charbuild/feat/Ghostly_Grasp) from liber Mortis. Which allows you to touch corporeal things.

**Becoming permanently corporeal**
this is discussed [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196300/how-can-a-permanently-remove-the-incorporeal-subtype-from-my-character)

Limits of this answer: I tried to include as many information as I was able to collect and review but I am sure I have missed something, thus I will edit this answer if I recieve any comment or find new information.

Also, in regards to Pat Ludwig's answer, the rules of incorporeals where updated from the Monster manual 1. Some of the handbooks where you find the updated rules of the incorporeal subtype rules are as follows:
*Monster Manual III* page 214
*Rule compendium* page 64
*Tome of Battle* page 79

Comment: Your initial 1 & 2 are virtually the same (*attack* vs. *attacks*). I didn't want to fix that but leave unfixed that *polymorph any object* inherits *polymorph* therefore forbidding incorporeality. However, but I didn't know if that was a mistake or if you had a different perspective on that than I or if you were subtly taking a controversial stance.

Comment: very interesting comment Hey I canChan, thank you. I agree that would be virtually the same if the rules of attacks between corporeal creatures and incorporeals were symmetrical, which is not the case. For such reason I decided to divide them. In regards to polymorph I thank you for making me notice this and will edit my answer eliminating polymorph of any object.

Comment: (I mean, literally, under *My answer is divided in 2 parts* there are points 1 & 2, and unless I'm seeing it wrong (it happens), they both say the same thing except one says *attack* and the other says *attacks.* They should be more different, yes?)

Comment: Oh thanks!!! I didn't get what you meant in your first message. I didn't realize I wrote it wrong! The second it is supposed to say "when incorporeal wants to hit corporeals" I' have edited it