# Do all incorporeal PCs have a 50% miss chance when attacking a corporeal creature?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, attack, incorporeal

In our D&D 3.5 campaign, for years, we have followed the rule provided in the *Monster Manual 1* on the incorporeal subtype. Summarizing: corporeals that hit an incorporeal have a 50% chance to miss, whereas incorporeals do not have any miss chance when hitting corporeals (as there is no mention of this in the description of the [incorporeal subtype](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype)).

This is in line with an answer given to a previous question from 2012: [Are ghost touch weapons the only way to bypass the 50% chance to ignore damage against or by incorporeal creatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13100/are-ghost-touch-weapons-the-only-way-to-bypass-the-50-chance-to-ignore-damage-a)

Of course, players in our campaign have followed the same rules, as they could go incorporeal with spells or their prestige class features.

Nonetheless, I have recently found the spell *ghostform* (*Spell Compendium*, page 103), whose description mentions that incorporeals have a 50% miss chance when hitting corporeals:

> Your attacks while in *ghostform* pass through (ignore) natural armor,
> armor, and shields, although deflection bonuses and force effects
> (such as *mage armor*) work normally against you. Nonmagical attacks you
> make with a melee weapon have no effect on corporeal targets, and any
> melee attack you make with a magic weapon against a corporeal target
> has a 50% miss chance, except for attacks you make with a ghost touch
> weapon, which are made normally (no miss chance). Spells you cast
> while in *ghostform* affect corporeal targets normally, including spells
> that require you to make an attack roll (such as rays or melee touch
> spells).

Do characters that become incorporeal (in any sort of way, e.g. spell, class feature, etc.) have a 50% miss chance when trying to hit a corporeal creature? What's the general rule?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (and I'd love to be corrected if I do), this doesn't seem to be stack answerable. The title question is pure survey which doesn't work here, and I'm not seeing a real problem in the body (but maybe it just drowned in between the lines?). This reads like it's just "I made this change, do you want to talk about it" to which the old adage that SE is a Q&A site, not a traditional forum might be useful. Questions should have a clear problem they want solved. [Oh, and you can [edit] this and when it's workable it'll be reopened.)

Comment: @Someone_Evil I think the subtext is *Is this change to incorporealness balanced?* but it would be nice were that instead text.

Comment: @HeyICanChan That seems like a reasonable possibility. Some words on what "balanced" means in 3.5e would also be good, no? (I ask this as mostly familiar with 3.5 from the gallery, as it were). Digius, your last paragraph seems to have had it's last half eaten by something, though I might just be better to trim it altogether as I'm not seeing what useful context it has on your question.

Comment: Thanks very much for the check, I have tried to make some changes and I hope it is now acceptable. I have also removed the last part despite I really wanted to ask if it is balanced to have incorporeal following the same rules as corporeal when they cast.  I interpreted your comment as it is not appropriate to talk about "balanced" and right or wrong in regards to homebrew rules, because this would lead to a not answerable question.

Comment: Ah, I think we may have had a crossing of wires. We can absolutely talk about balance (we have a lot of homebrew questions which do), but term is slightly nebulous. Therefore it's often useful (or necessary) to clarify what balance you're going for, or more commonly clarify what something is supposed to be balanced against. That's especially important with homebrew that is not new (player/character) options. The last paragraph was also not about homebrew was it?

Comment: The question seems perfectly clear to me as “source A doesn’t say anything about this, but source B claims it does: what’s the actual rule?”

Comment: @KRyan looking back, the original version was badly opinion based. This version is as you say.

Comment: @fectin Eh, no? It asked if it was the right call to make things symmetric, implicitly, would this be balanced, and implicitly, that’s “what would be the balance ramifications of this ruling?” which is a question for expert opinion but not a popularity poll. That would have been fine, though obviously the original question had fairly difficult to follow writing/formatting that definitely needed cleaning up either way.

Comment: Digius's followup question is here: [What are the implications of making the rules between corporeal creatures and incorporeal creatures symmetrical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/196297/33569)

Comment: Hello, I decided to open a new topic with the other question after I read someone_evil's and KRyan's comments. I thank you both for your time and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect of being incorporeal was updated in *Monster Manual III* (the updated version is also reprinted in *Rules Compendium* and *Tome of Battle*, and possibly elsewhere). Strictly speaking, there are [problems with supplements updating core rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37466/4563), which may interest you, but ultimately you probably want to use the update.

Anyway, *ghostform* is more consistent with the updated version of incorporeal. The rule about nonmagical incorporeal weapons having no effect on corporeal targets, and magical incorporeal weapons having a 50% chance of effect, is the same both for *ghostform* and the updated rules for incorporeal creatures.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time to write the answer, very helpful. I found it curious that in the MM V the incorporeal subtype description does not mention spells casted by incorporeals at all.

Comment: @Digius “Similarly, spells cast by an incorporeal creature affect corporeal creatures normally,” _Monster Manual V_ pg. 213. This is consistent with what’s printed in _Monster Manual III_, _Rules Compendium_, and _Tome of Battle_, as well as with *ghostform*.

Comment: Can't believe I read it 3 times and I wrote the comment because I could   not find it! Thank you for correcting me, I found it now.